# How to make html content editable while viewing it in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm working on Electron app and I'm aiming to let people edit html content while viewing it in app. For example edit that header and button text. Then all changes should be saved.

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEOJe.png)

So in my opinion I should:

1. Give special id's or class names to that object and manipulate with js to display edit window instead of button for example, change text, press ok and it should save it. Is there any way to do that? Maybe a library or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to answer, as your project is in such an early stage, maybe [content editable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) is what you want to use, but this would mean you have to develop it all from scratch

But yeah your idea sounds ok too, have a button to switch the page into a kind of edit mode, let the user change elements of the page and finally save the modified version before turning it back to view mode

Or you use a library like react and use plugins like this [content editable plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable) or use a wysiwyg editor like [draft](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Wysiwyg actually isn't what I was looking for because I need to edit already existing content, info on mozilla website:  **contenteditable="true"** is just right. I make changes, press save, it gets data using **innerHTML** and saves.